# How to find the explicit formula for the heat kernel of the Grushin Operator?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

How to find the explicit formula for the heat kernel of the Grushin Operator?
I been reading this and dont understand the intermediate steps to get from (1.16) to (1.17),what methods are needed?
https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspa.2014.0943

Comment: (1.17) is the heat kernel of the Heisenberg sub-Laplacian, which you just asked another question about. The heat kernel of the Grushin operator is given in (1.22).  There is a reference given [21], have you checked it?

Comment: I was just wondering how to generalise such results to other types of Grushin Operators,besides the Sub-Laplacian(which is a Grushin Operator in the Heisenberg Group)